# Is there a "bookmark/headline" Syntax for a document outline in Python/pyCharm, like #### works in R/RStudio?

Tags: python, pycharm

Coding R in RStudio allows you to bracket comments in `####` to generate a "table of contents" that one can use to jump back and forth to different code sections. I love the lean and quick way tis allows for structuring my code (like Markdown does for text documents). An example is shown below.

Is there a similar feature for python using pyCharm?

How it works in R is really comfortable:

```
#-------------------------#
####  MY CODE CHAPTER  ####
#-------------------------#
do = this
if(this == lengthy) {
  print("structuring code with the ####-elements can be really handy to have "Bookmarks" to jump to")
} else return

#-------------------------#
#### NEXT CODE CHAPTER ####
#-------------------------#
do = something_else
```

Which generates "bookmarks" or simply entries as shown in the following picture:
[image: RStudio #### entries become outline-entries1]

I was hoping the "Structure" tab in pyCharm would be useful in a similar fashion, but I'd like to create my own structure independent of functions, fields and classes (with fields somehow always being alphabetically ordered, even though the feature is turned off).
[image: Structure tab in PyCharm, alphabetical ordering turned off]

Answer (score 0):

One option is using bookmarks in pyCharm. They can be added like break points:
[image: bookmarks in pycharm]

This is more flexible, as the `####` style in R/RStudio, but also more circumstancial, and it has a major drawback: These bookmarks (most likely, not tested) don't "carry" over with the code. If someone else opens the file in his own pyCharm, he'll has to set the bookmarks manually again.